# Date day/minute in mongodb queries

Tags: mongodb, datetime, time-series, isodate

I have time series data stored in a mongodb database, where one of the fields is an ISODate object. I'm trying to retrieve all items for which the ISODate object has a zero value for minutes and seconds. That is, all the objects that have a timestamp at a round hour.

Is there any way to do that, or do I need to create separate fields for hour, min, second, and  query for them directly by doing, e.g., find({"minute":0, "second":0})?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this as @Devesh says or if it fits better you could use the aggregation framework:

```
db.col.aggregate([
   {$project: {_id:1, date: {mins: {$minute: '$dateField'}, secs: {$second: '$dateField'}}}},
   {$match: {mins: 0, secs: 0}}
]);
```

Like so.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually what i was looking for, but Devesh's answer may lead to better performance in my case since I'll be running a huge number of queries with these constraints.

Comment: @user1094206 indeed, pre-aggregating to another field, selectively and carefully will produce faster and more scalable results, however I would not use a date time column since there is no such thing in MongoDB only a date column, instead you would house an object whose parts form a date, i.e.: `date: {hours: 1, mins: 0, secs: 0}`

Answer (score 4):

Use the **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#op._S_expr)** operator along with the date aggregate operators **[`$minute`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/minute/)** and **[`$second`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/second/)** in your find query as:

```
db.collection.find({
    '$expr': {
        '$and': [
            { '$eq': [ { '$minute': '$dateField' }, 0 ] },
            { '$eq': [ { '$second': '$dateField' }, 0 ] },
        ]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you have one more column added in the collection only containing the datetime without minutes and seconds . It will make your query faster and easy to use. It will be datetime column with no minutes and seconds parts

Comment: That seems like a good idea. I will go with that unless there is a way to filter directly based on min/sec.